# How to get lat long top left and bottom right google map javascript api v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have map google, i want get lat long (top left) and (bottom right)  of map. how to get it?
Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

getBounds() gives you a LatLngBounds-objects, which contains the NE-and SW-coordinates of the current viewport. Shouldn't be so hard to conclude the NW and SE